# Interpreting Data Sheets ("Typical Applications")

Tags: rf, datasheet, transceiver

I've recently been researching various transceivers, but I run into trouble as soon as I get to the "typical applications" section of the data sheet.

With the [Si4464](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/Si4464-63-61-60.pdf) for instance, the example application provided does not specify recommended capacitor/inductor values.  The circuit diagram (page 16) is provided below:

[image]

There are not footnotes provided for the figure.  The figure is only referenced once in the entire document (page 15):

> Figure 2 demonstrates an application for +20 dBm using an external T/R-switch.

My intuition tells me that the capacitor/inductor values are not specified because I am expected to know how to choose them myself.  If that is the case, what principles should I use to determine the values?  If not, am I missing some crucial information hidden in the data sheet?

Comment: Your intuition is correct. These sorts of devices are not intended for novices in the related field.

Comment: The Si4464 has a working RF range of 119-1050 Mhz. There is no possible way ever that you could have a antenna impedance matching network that worked well over that entire range without enormous complexity.

Comment: It's also worth noting that even if the datasheet did have part values, the actual part selection, and particularly the PCB layout requires a deep and intimate understanding of how the circuitry works anyways. RF PCB layout is non-trivial.

Comment: Often for these sorts of devices it's worth looking for development boards / reference designs to see if they match the frequency you're after. For example the following is for 915 MHz: http://www.silabs.com/products/wireless/Pages/RFMD-Reference-Design.aspx

Comment: You might also want to read AN643: http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/AN643.pdf, specifically chapter 4.